# Are StackExchange.Redis fire-and-forget calls guaranteed to be delivered in order?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis, redis-streams

If I make multiple [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) calls from a single thread using [fire-and-forget](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html#sync-vs-async-vs-fire-and-forget), are they guaranteed to be delivered in order?

Use case: I am adding an item to a Redis stream and then using pub/sub to trigger another service to process that stream. To avoid a race condition, I need to make sure that the item is added to the stream before the pub/sub message is delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most StackExchange.Redis APIs are thread-safe, the order of delivery of commands sent through SE.Redis can't be *guaranteed* out-of-the-box in your scenario for several reasons:

- your topology could have multiple nodes, where each message of your sequence is delivered to a different node for a change in the topology or according to your own preferences (`CommandFlags.Prefer*` / `CommandFlags.Demand*`);
- your thread could host multiple tasks whose continuations do not respect the intended delivery order;
- being fire-and-forget, a failure in the delivery of the first command would not stop sending the subsequent ones;

> I need to make sure that the item is added to the stream before the pub/sub message is delivered.

I suggest using a [Lua script](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting.html) to solve this, which would execute your commands within the same atomic unit and against the same node:

```lua
redis.call('XADD', 'foo', '*', 'bar', 'baz')
redis.call('PUBLISH', 'foo-added', '')
```